# how to create a classes from mogodb

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Can someone give me an example of code for mapping with morphia and mongodb?
This is my class which contains database fields.  I don't know how to 
make the connection between morphia and mongodb.

```
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.*;

//@Entity
//define the name of the collection where this entity will be stored

@Entity("tabes")
class MappingMorphia {
    @Id
    String id;

    String FACILITY;
    String HOST;
    String MESSAGE;
    String PID;
    String PRIORITY;
    String PROGRAM;
    int SEQNUM;
    String SOURCE;
    String SOURCEIP;
    String TAGS;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are examples aplenty at the morphia github site:  https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb doesn't understand about classes as is, or at least not the way you are thinking. There is, however, a module called mongoose that lets your model your objects. I think that will suit you.

Here's a link to mongoose's docs

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html

Comment: He's using morphia (or trying to) so that object model works just fine.